# How to correctly display metric units in browser

Tags: css, browser

I want to display "natural size" pictures of goods on web site. 
First of course i calculate size of picture :

```
<Height of picture in pixels> * <real height of item in mm>
-----------------------------------------------------------
        <height of item on the picture in pixels>
```

Formula is logicaly correct and it works fine on

```
desktop 17'' 4:3 monitor 1280*1024.
```

Any other device shows metrics wrong.
I test:

```
2 smartphone.
22'' 1920*1080 desktop monitor
13.3'' 1366*768 notebook
14'' 1600*900 notebook
```

They all not 4:3 aspect ratio.
what's wrong with that? How can i reach my goal?
I search web but only workaround i found is to display piece of A4 size paper and ask user zoom page.
I better ask user to setup their system, but how to do it?

Comment: you really expect people to hold up a piece of paper to adjust THEIR systems to accommodate YOUR reality? If your real goods are (say) a cube 1m on each side, are you going to require that your users go out and buy a screen that's 1 square meter so you can display in "natural size"?

Comment: No, the goods are at most 20 cm size :) Users want to know real size of item. To do so when i foe example buy something on another site i draw a picture on blat of paper. If i can just adjust zoom of picture it will be more simpler. Of course it will be better if size will be correct out of the box. I have many another picture of items, which fits the screen, but one is big - natural size. There is my site : www.cynephone.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all! I combined all of tips and make picture : 
http://www.clker.com/clipart-258249.html
user takes one of common thing and fit it to picture by zoom.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, although methods exist to query the browser for the exact pixels per inch of its display, the browser vendors decided to agree to a convenient lie... all browsers report 96 pixels per inch. Although you can get a browser to report this fact to you, there is no way to get the *real* pixels per inch.

A famous example is that there is no way through Javascript, HTML, or CSS to detect the difference between an IPad 2 and an IPad Mini, despite having radically different pixel density.

Actually I find the approach of using the paper and asking the user to zoom to calibrate the "real displayed size" rather clever. If you make it easy to use, I'm sure they will appreciate this feature!

Comment: Thank you for this decision ! Now i understand why desktop 17'' 4:3 monitor 1280*1024 works. It have really 96 dpi. Can you tell me, this issue

Comment: Thank you for this workaround ! Now i understand why desktop 17'' 4:3 monitor 1280*1024 works. It have really 96 dpi. But i not query dpi directly - i just use metric values in css. I can't believe - this feature just not work at all? Only with 96 dpi monitors? Wow :(((

Comment: So there is now way to setup browser once to display metrics correct?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, by CSS 2.1 specs, the `mm` unit (and similar units like `cm` and `in`) relate to physical units. So if you set an image width in `mm` units, browsers should scale the image to the given physical measure, with the accuracy allowed by the resolution of the device.

In reality, browsers behave more the way described in the CSS3 Values and Units CR. The section on [physical units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) says that `1in` equals `96px` by definition, and on high-resolution devices like printers, the inch is the anchor unit, corresponding to real physical inch, whereas on lower-resolution devices like displays, the pixel is the anchor unit. It adds: “Note that if the anchor unit is the pixel unit, the physical units might not match their physical measurements.” (Besides, even in printers, the correspondence between CSS `in` and a physical inch is not necessarily exact.)

So, mission impossible.

For calibration by the user, I would not use an A4 paper. It’s large, and not everyone has A4 papers at hand, especially in countries with a different standard paper size. A ruler, with both inches and millimeters, would be better. And perhaps you could add a zooming widget to make the zooming easier.